# Classification of Shape Of You?

Tags: genre

How would you classify songs such as Alan Walker-Faded, Alone, Spectre, Shape Of You, Counting Stars, Waving Flag and Cheap Thrills? Would they come under semi-classical, light pop(anything exists like this?) or lite music?

Comment: @alephzero Do the guys of Music SE think we are their garbage can?

Comment: @Bebs I don't think that's fair.  We [badly need more questions here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans), and genre-identification questions are on-topic for us.  I don't find this a bad or inappropriate migration at all.

Comment: @ChrisSunami I agree genre ID questions are allowed but this one has several songs or artists (we don't even know which one is a title or an artist)... the problem is not the ID part, but the zero effort and several questions in one.

Comment: @Bebs I agree the question needs work, but I don't want to be angry with the Music mods for sending it to us.  We are averaging less than 2 new questions per day!

Comment: @Bebs then close it. you don't have to keep the migration, but because this question is allowed per scope and we haven't had any real discussion on  what these questions should look like it makes sense to migrate . I helped bring it here because we do allow these kinds of questions and Music SE 100% does not. We can clean it up or split it out, but it still belongs here and if we want to have a quality check for the questions we need to enforce it regardless of where it comes from.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the sound of current pop.  "Pop" is itself considered a "lite" genre (i.e. a simplified, less complex, less challenging, more mass-audience-friendly version of other genres), there's not much need to add another modifier.  Several of these songs have reggaeton, reggae, dancehall and EDM influences, but that's true of most current pop, which could be considered "lite reggae" or "lite EDM" in the same way that older pop was often "lite rock."

I don't hear any particular "classical" influence in any of these songs.

Comment: Would Yiruma be classical? It sounds classical, only piano but it is very short.

Answer (score 1):

The songs listed are classified in different genres.  What unites them into any group is that they are **pop music**.  And even then, they are not united in their own sub-genres.  Some of the songs you list are West End Pop, others Hollywood Pop. **Wavin(g)' Flag**, I assume you are refering to the K'Naan song, is Canpop (Canadian pop).  Pop music is heavily tied to the theatre scenes where the audiences are more interested in familiar, pluralist narratives.  As this is the case, pop music can be separated by which theatre scene it is associated with.

Apart from that, all the songs you list employ simplified rhythms or rhythms borrowed from other genres onto a more standardised rhythm of the theatre scenes they are associated with.  If you want a classic example, traditional pop and swing music based around Broadway and New York City use 8-bars strictly while swing music from other regions of the US such as the south use more 12-bar passages in their music.  The 8 bars come directly from Tin Pan Alley where it had become the standard format in New York City.

**Edit**: because further commentary was desired on the connection of the theatre scenes and pop music.

Theatre scenes are important for pop music because they are a connection point for composers, librettists, producers, choreographers, singers, instrumentalists, stage technicians and dancers.  These are key components for putting on big shows for the top numbers.  Record labels interested in promoting their releases with a high visual presence would be wise to be closely associated with theatre professionals as well as marketing professionals.  Music is rarely only the music.  Rather, the performance is a show and this is especially true for pop music.

Hollywood has been a very important point of interest for musicians looking to hit it big time in North America.  While the number of musicals from Hollywood have fallen in the last few decades, the infusion of music from top record labels is often apparent in the movies of today.  The coordination between Hollywood and the top record labels is not more apparent than, as an example, [Katy Perry's show at Superbowl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZD1QrIe--_Y).  Here, the costuming, choreography, lighting, dancing and fireworks all require professionals from the local theatre¹ scene but also the top names found in Hollywood.

¹ Recall little old Left Shark who tried.

Comment: I've never heard of the association between theater scenes and current pop before.  Can you elaborate or add some citations?

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I meant K'Naan. What about time signatures?

Comment: What about time signatures?